# How fast and big would the waves be in the rocks from the Richter scale 10 earthquake at Chixulub

Tags: geology, earthquakes

If I was near Australia and China when the 10km meteorite hit Chixulub 65 million years ago, the first thing I would have noticed is an earthquake high above magnitude 9, and the ground would shake by perhaps an entire meter up and down and side to side I don't know how fast perhaps at the speed of sound? Is that wrong and what about places closer to the impact? Later there would be tsunamis and the entire planet would be hot and all the super volcanoes be flowing for ages and then it would be freezing for years. So what about the shakes that the birds, rats, dinos, frogs, rivers and trees had to deal with?